# ArrayList Cannot find variable isJunior

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to call a boolean varible from another class to a class which contains an arraylist. The purpose of the method below is to add a student to the team, and if the student falls under a certain age (eg 18) they receive a discount.

Here is the code for the boolean result of whether a student is a Junior or not:

```
public boolean isJunior()
{
   return age < 18;
}
```

The arraylist class contains a method sighUp() which adds a student to the team list. if the student is a junior they receive a discount:

```
public void signUp(Student jj)
{
   team.add(jj);
   points = points + 1;
   if (Student.isJunior = true)
   {
      totalCosts = totalCosts + (cost / 2);
   }
```

The error I keep getting is 'isJunior' is a variable that cannot be found. I am trying to call this method from the student class which contains the boolean variable. Anyone to shed some light on this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you want is

```
 if (jj.isJunior())
```

This invokes the method `isJunior()` on the `Student` instance `jj`. The method returns a boolean. This boolean is evaluated by the `if` statement.

You don't need an additional `== true`, because

```
 jj.isJunior() == true
```

is a boolean expression that evaluates to `true` if the return value of `isJunior()` is `true`. Thus the boolean expression's result is the same as the boolean value returned by `isJunior()` itself.

Comment: I've changed it to this and checking if it complies and works

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors in your code.

1. not using instance jj which is the method parameter
2. not using equality operator
3. not using the getter method

use the instance jj and the getter.

```
 if (jj.isJunior() == true)
```

You can also omit == true and just use  `if (jj.isJunior())`

Answer (score -2):

I guess this is what you need :

```
if (jj.isJunior()== True )  
                       {  
                            totalCosts+=cost/2  
                       }
```

you've forgotten the parentheses for isJunior method.

Comment: There are two answers already, and your code does neither compile nor do you point out all 3 errors made by the OP.

Comment: well I've just read the answers, I'm new on your forum and I see that people here are very fast, the plus of my answer is totalCosts+=cost/2 I guess though

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @mounaim I'm new here as well and I just saw another question that got "answered" 10 times in a minute...

Comment: @mounaim The error is in `True`- it starts with a capital letter

Comment: LOL.. this is funny :)